# is there any sdk support from gcp to get list of iam users,service accounts and the corresponding roles attached to them?

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

i need java software development kit preferably.
[image shows how to view the required data in console.i want the same through software development kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqUn4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Start with the Google Cloud Java libraries: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/

Comment: i searched all libraries provided by google including java.There is no such method i found.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of users, service accounts and their corresponding roles upon running the below command from the cloud shell. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy).

$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT_ID]

If you want to do it programmatically, you can leverage the Cloud API. Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy), there is an example for JAVA too.